# How to get attribute from dropdown

Tags: magento2

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct();  ?>
<?= __("<br />Czas wysyłki zwykle w ") ?>           <?php $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getLeadtimeToShip(), null, true);?>
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getLeadtimeToShip(), 'leadtime_to_ship'); ?>
```

From above code when attribute is "text" then I without any issue get and display in frontend.

Issue is when  attribute is dropdown option. Then instand of attribute magento get https://prnt.sc/12d61rw 7373

Does anyone have any idea how to get the attribute dropdown option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the frontend label for dropdown use code like this

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct();  ?>
<?php $leadtimeAttr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('leadtime_to_ship');
$leadtimeToShip = (string)$leadtimeAttr->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
<?php echo $leadtimeToShip; ?>
```